# How to identify a text file is not using any other process

Tags: c#, filestream

I have 2 windows services. First windows service will compare  2 text files and it will generate a comparison result file.  Once result file is created, FileSystemWatcher will catch the file create event and trigger the second windows service. Then second windows service start to read the content of the result file. There is a scenario that comparison result file is created but its' content still writing to the file.
Because of that, second windows service give me an error that file is consuming by another process. To prevent that I used the following method.

```
private FileContent GetFileContent(string path)
{
        FileContent f = null;
        try
        {
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(FileContent));
            FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open);
            f =  (FileContent)serializer.Deserialize(fileStream);
            fileStream.Dispose();

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
           f = GetFileContent(path);
        }
        return f;
}
```

Besides this method, is there any way to wait until the file is released its' current consuming process then read it?

Comment: Suggest that the `catch` delays a 'bit` before trying again.

Comment: They way you are handling exception it could go in infinite loop..

Comment: I would strongly recommend not doing what you currently do.  A brief delay before the retry would make it safer, but it's still not good.  You could basically end up stuck in that loop forever if a file inadvertently gets left open.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya exact my point. I also thought about that. But I could not think of a proper way to do this. That is why I post this.

Comment: @Archer any suggestion on proper way to do this

Comment: @Archer It points to your duplicate question. Thank you